# How to post Form data and File in the same submit with Angular 4 in .NET Core

Tags: c#, angular, angular4-forms

I am trying to add in the Suppliers table a new entry. This table also has another one linked to it in which are stored the contracts with each supplier.
The desired functionality is to submit in the same form both the data for the new Supplier and the contract, but I can't make it work.

I am able to add a new supplier and after the contract by uploading the file separately in another form, but not in the same submit action.

How can I do that?

My form looks like this:

```
<form class="form-material m-t-40" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group has-warning">
        <h4 class="entity-info"><label for="denumire" class="label-has-danger"> Denumire furnizor </label></h4>
        <input type="text" id="denumire" name="denumire" class="form-control" placeholder="Denumire" [(ngModel)]="furnizor.denumire" #denumire="ngModel">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-warning">
        <h4 class="entity-info"><label for="cod" class="label-has-danger"> Cod intern furnizor </label></h4>
        <input type="text" id="cod" name="cod" class="form-control" placeholder="Cod intern" [(ngModel)]="furnizor.cod" #cod="ngModel">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-warning">
        <h4 class="entity-info"><label for="cod" class="label-has-success"> Cod de inregistrare fiscala furnizor </label></h4>
        <input type="text" id="codIntern" name="codIntern" class="form-control" placeholder="Cod" [(ngModel)]="furnizor.codIntern" #codIntern="ngModel">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-warning">
        <h4 class="entity-info"><label for="adresa" class="label-has-success"> Adresa </label></h4>
        <input type="text" id="adresa" name="adresa" class="form-control" placeholder="Adresa" [(ngModel)]="furnizor.adresa">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-warning">
        <h4 class="entity-info"><label for="persoanaContact" class="label-has-success"> Persoana Contact </label></h4>
        <input type="text" id="persoanaContact" name="persoanaContact" class="form-control" placeholder="Persoana Contact" [(ngModel)]="furnizor.persoanaContact" #reprezentant="ngModel">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-warning">
        <h4 class="entity-info"><label for="telefon" class="label-has-success"> Telefon </label></h4>
        <input type="tel" id="telefon" name="telefon" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefon" [(ngModel)]="furnizor.telefon" #telefon="ngModel">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-warning">
        <h4 class="entity-info"><label for="dataIncepereContract" class="label-has-success"> Data incepere contract </label></h4>
        <input type="date" class="form-control m-b-40" placeholder="2017-06-04" id="dataIncepereContract" name="dataIncepereContract" [(ngModel)]="furnizor.dataIncepereContract" #dataIncepereContract="ngModel">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group has-warning">
        <h4 class="entity-info"><label for="dataExpirareContract" class="label-has-success"> Data expirare contract </label></h4>
        <input type="date" class="form-control m-b-40" placeholder="2017-06-04" id="dataExpirareContract" name="dataExpirareContract" [(ngModel)]="furnizor.dataExpirareContract" #dataExpirareContract="ngModel">
    </div>

    <input type="file" #fileInput>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-add animated flipInX flipInY lightSpeedIn slideInUp" (click)="submit()">
        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save
    </button>
</form>
```

I have tried a lot of options and combinations for the file and the other form fields, but none work.

My ts file reads the file input like this:

```
...

@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;

...
submit() {
   var nativeElement: HTMLInputElement = this.fileInput.nativeElement;

   if (nativeElement.files) this.file = nativeElement.files[0];
   this.furnizorService.create(this.furnizor, this.file).subscribe(() => {});
}
```

My service:

```
create(furnizor: any, fileToUpload: any) {

    let input = new FormData();
    input.append("file", fileToUpload);

    furnizor.file = input;

    return this.http.post('/api/furnizor', furnizor).map(res => res.json());
}
```

And in my C# Controller I tried:

```
[HttpPost("/api/furnizor")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateFurnizor([FromBody]FurnizorResource furnizorResource)
    {
    ...
    }
```

Where I added a new property

```
public IFormFile file { get; set; }
```

in FurnizorResource, but if I do this, furnizorResource is not mapped and is null.

I also tried sending them separately (just to try):

```
[HttpPost("/api/furnizor")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateFurnizor([FromBody]FurnizorResource furnizorResource, IFormFile file)
{
...
}
```

(Which obviously doesn't work since in the Angular service I can't send 2 "body" elements). With this method the furnizorResource data is correct, but of course file is null...

How can I post Json data and a file at the same time in Angular 4.3.6 and ASP.NET Core 2?

Comment: I understand that both, Angular and c# must be the property contracts that it will be a array of contract

    interface IForniture
    {
        cod:number;
        ...
        contracts :IContracts[]
     }. But I don't see the way you add this contracts

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question, but if you are asking how I store the Contracts in the database, that is not important for now, I just need to get the file to the backend first

Comment: Try to explain better

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like that? That's teh way I use it in my app and it works.

```
var formData = new FormData()
for (var key in model)
    formData.append(key, furnizor[key])

formData.append('file', fileToUpload)

let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' })
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })
return this.authHttp.post('/api/furnizor', formData, options).map(res => res.json())
```

Comment: I tried it like this input.append("furnizorResource", furnizor); input.append("file", fileToUpload); and with headers and options, but I get Internal Server Error without even hitting the API method

Comment: It does not go to my API. I do not know where this exception is thrown, but the breakpoint at the first line of code in the API that it should get is not hit. I just get an Internal Server Error in the console. If I do not attach a file, the breakpoint is hit. With the same code

Comment: @AndreiDobrin please check my edted answer - i forgot to add file to the formData

Comment: Yes, but I didn't forgot. I get the above error with the file being added

Answer (score -1):

I understand that your  both, Angular and c# must be the property fornitureResources that it will be a array of FornitureResource

```
interface Forniture
{
    cod:number;
    ...
    fornitureResources :IFromFile[]
 }
```

So, e.g.

```
let myforniture={
     cod:1,
     ...
     fornitureResources:[
         { file:"file1"},
         { file:"file2"}
     ]
  }
```

If you send "myforniture" using this.http.post('/api/furnizor', myforniture) you must be get a "Forniture" in your API

Comment: I see no IFormFile in your code. How can an Array help me post a file to the backend?